# Insert python object in mongodb

Tags: python, json, mongodb

Folks,
I just spent a good amount of time trying to look this up -- I ought to be missing something basic.

I have a python object, all I want to do is to insert this object in mondodb.

This is what I have:

```
from pymongo import Connection
import json

conn = Connection()
db = conn.cl_database
postings = db.postings_collection

class Posting(object):
    def __init__(self, link, found=None, expired=None):
        self.link = link
        self.found = found
        self.expired = expired

posting = Posting('objectlink1')
value = json.dumps(posting, default=lambda x:x.__dict__)
postings.insert(value)
```

throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mongotry.py", line 21, in <module>
postings.insert(value)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/pymongo/collection.py", line 302, in insert
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/pymongo/database.py", line 252, in _fix_incoming
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/pymongo/son_manipulator.py", line 73, in transform_incoming
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Seems like it is because json.dumps() returns a string.

Now if I do do a loads of the value before inserting it works fine:

```
posting = Posting('objectlink1')
value = json.dumps(posting, default=lambda x:x.__dict__)
value = json.loads(value)
postings.insert(value)
```

What is the most straight-forward to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What is `value` in your initial code?

It should be `dict` not class instance

This should work:

```
postings.insert(posting.__dict__)
```

Comment: Sorry I realized I missed a line there, just edited the question.

Comment: Jeez, that's right. Thanks, feel stupid to have missed something so silly.

Answer (score 3):

You are misusing the insert method for the collection. Review here:  http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert

What you need to be inserting is a document. It should be a dict with keys and values. Simply trying to insert a string is not appropriate. json.dumps returns a string in json format. If you are just dumping it to get a dict then the json step is not necessary.

Insert exactly how your documents should look:

postings.insert({"key":"value"})

Or convert your class instance directly into the dict you want to store as a doc and then insert it. It works with your json.dumps.loads() because that ultimately does give you a dict.

Comment: How to insert leaving outer of nested dictionary here in this question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59499237/insert-multiple-json-files-to-mongodb-using-python/59500144?noredirect=1#59500144