# Insert Multiple JSON files to MongoDB using python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

The JSON files are as follows a.json,b.json.....z.json (26 json files)

The json format of each of the file looks as:

```
{
    "a cappella": {
        "word": "a cappella",
        "wordset_id": "5feb6f679a",
        "meanings": [
            {
                "id": "492099d426",
                "def": "without musical accompaniment",
                "example": "they performed a cappella",
                "speech_part": "adverb"
            },
            {
                "id": "0bf8d49e2e",
                "def": "sung without instrumental accompaniment",
                "example": "they sang an a cappella Mass",
                "speech_part": "adjective"
            }
        ]
    },
    "A.D.": {
        "word": "A.D.",
        "wordset_id": "b7e9d406a0",
        "meanings": [
            {
                "id": "a7482f3e30",
                "def": "in the Christian era",
                "speech_part": "adverb",
                "synonyms": [
                    "AD"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },.........
}
```

How could I store these in MongoDB such that if queried with `word` the results shows `meanings`,`synonyms`(if available)?

I have never used Mongo on how to approach, but the same was done with SO suggestions for a single json file in mysql as:

**cursor has db connection

```
with open('a.json') as f:
    d = json.load(f)

for word in d:
    word_obj = d[word]
    wordset_id = word_obj['wordset_id']

    sql = "INSERT INTO Word (word, wordset_id) VALUES (%s, %s)"
    values = (word, wordset_id)
    cursor.execute(sql, values)
    conn.commit()
```

similarly to store meanings and synonyms as different tables,

But as suggetsed I guess this would become better if MongoDB is used

Comment: Sorry, but "I have never used Mongo" just begs for a tutorial on that topic. Run through that first. Then, try to replicate these things in Python. Stack Overflow can't teach you things from scratch and it doesn't want to either.

Comment: makes sense, I can connect to mongo , but looking for an approach on inserting all json files at once , thanks for suggestion

Comment: looks like you're using `SQL` not `MongoDB`

Comment: Yeah I have tried with sql , same I want to replicate with mongo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert data from multiple `.json` files, do it in a loop:

```py
file_names = ['a.json', 'b.json', ...]

for file_name in file_names:
    with open(file_name) as f:
        file_data = json.load(f)  # load data from JSON to dict
        for k, v in file_data.items():  # iterate over key-value pairs
            collection.insert_one(v)  # your collection object here
```

Comment: when I am just trying with a.json single file as test, it has thrown an error : bson.errors.InvalidDocument: key 'A.D.' must not contain '.'         (this data is in above question)

Comment: In mongo, keys cannot contain `.` character. If your files contain `.` only at top level, it's okay since they are not inserted in collection (in my example answer). Otherwise you should change key names.

Comment: Is there any alternate for this (`check_keys= False`) instead of changing key names?

Comment: No, because `.` is used in their query language like `key1.key2`

Comment: yeah thanks mate , i just read the docs , should I know now filter whole json keys before inserting , any better suggeston?

Comment: Well sometimes people just replace `.` with `_`. If you need to "restore" your keys to their "original" format in future and avoid collisions with real "_" character, you can use your own custom char sequence to encode `.`. Like double underscores or something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204939/discussion-between-codenewbie-and-ivan-vinogradov).

Comment: Hey @Ivan do you have any idea on creating collections dynamically such that a_col has a.json data, b_col has b.json data and so on......so that when on querying the time would reduce instead of having whole data in one collection, This can be done using an ORM? or the way you explained is good enough?

Comment: What you wrote above sounds exactly like table partitioning. I haven't used this feature in Mongo, but you can google for that. I have no details on your application features, so partitioning may not be the most efficient trick you can use.

Comment: sure mate, thanks, The thing I am trying this is , the collection contains the whole words information (like meanins,synonyms) similar to a online dictionary, so when user search a particular word say starts with letter 'a ' if we have separate collection for 'a' then instead of querying whole single collection it would have better performance to query just 'a_col' collection as we knew this before,  hope you got this